# Insert checkboxes values to database with assigned field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I am inserting values like below from my form

```
<span class="field"><input type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name" class="input-small" value="<?php echo set_value('item_name'); ?>" />    

<span class="field"><input type="checkbox" name="tag_id[]" value="<?php echo $value['tag_id']; ?>" /></span>
```

for first field I wanna insert into following item_table

```
+----------+--------------+
| item_id  |   item_name  | 
+-------------+-----------+
| 1        | A            |
| 2        | B            |
| 3        | C            |
| 4        | D            |
| 5        | E            |
+----------+--------------+
```

for second field I want to insert checkboxes values to following table like these.

```
+----------+--------------+
| item_id  |     tag_id  | 
+-------------+-----------+
| 1        | 1            |
| 1        | 2            |
| 2        | 1            |
| 2        | 2            |
| 2        | 3            |
+----------+--------------+
```

In my model function

```
$item_name = $this->input->post('item_name');

        $data_to_store = array(
            'item_name' => $item_name            
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('item_table', $data_to_store);
        return $insert;
```

How should I insert checkboxes values to second table according to Item id?

Comment: From what I understand, you just have to print a Checkbox for each `tag_id` and give them the ID as values. When sending the form just read the sent values. In my opinion, a Multiple Select would be better though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use 2 methods.

```
function tableItem($data)
{
    $item_name = $this->input->post('item_name');

    $data_to_store = array(
        'item_name' => $item_name            
    );
    $this->db->insert('item_table', $data_to_store);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->tableTag($moreData,$id);
}

function tableTag($theData,$itemID)
{
    foreach($theData as $d)
    {
        $data_to_store = array(
            'tag_id' => $d,
            'item_id' => $itemID           
        );
        $this->db->insert('tag_table', $data_to_store);
    }
}
```

Or you can combine both methods in one.

Remember to add error handlers for the inserts.